# How can I update values in state from one function rather than each value having its own event listener?

Tags: reactjs, state

Background,  I am currently working on a Food Truck Finder application based in React.  In react, as I understand it, if you want to change the value in state you have to have a listener like:

```
handleTruckTypeChange = (idx) => (e) => {
    const newTrucks = this.state.data.map((truck, sidx) => {
      if (idx !== sidx) return truck;
      return { ...truck, type: e.target.value };
    });

    this.setState({ data: newTrucks });
  }
```

which works fine for some of my other values in the table but I have a large object for my schedule object.  Its handling dozens of values and I don't want to have to write a special event listener for each one.  On top of that I have an array of these schedule objects using idx as an index.  for example, each day has a startTime, endTime, openClosed, and cost.

Is there a way they can all be handled by the same event listener so I'm not making 7 copies of the same function to handle each change?

an example of how I'm calling the onChange.

```
<td>
 <FormControl className={classes.margin}>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="openClosed">O/C</InputLabel>
  <NativeSelect
    id="openClosed"
    value={this.state.schedule[idx].monOpen}
    onChange={this.handleScheduleChange(idx)}
    input={<BootstrapInput />}
  >
   <option aria-label="None" value="" />
   <option value={"0"}>Open</option>
   <option value={"1"}>Closed</option>
  </NativeSelect>
 </FormControl>
</td>
```

Comment: right now by doing `return { ...truck, type: e.target.value };` each time the same `type` key in object is modified, or you have some special `[type]` there? becuase store it as `[idx]: e.target.value` and then `stata.data[idx]` is the relevant truck in data

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function handleOnChange

```
handleOnChange = field => event => {
    this.setState({[field]: event.target.value})
  }
```

and now you can call this function whenever you need to update state with the state that you want to change as parameter.

For your scenario

```
<td>
 <FormControl className={classes.margin}>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="openClosed">O/C</InputLabel>
  <NativeSelect
    id="openClosed"
    value={this.state.schedule[idx].monOpen}
    onChange={this.handleOnChange('schedule[idx].monOpen')}
    input={<BootstrapInput />}
  >
   <option aria-label="None" value="" />
   <option value={"0"}>Open</option>
   <option value={"1"}>Closed</option>
  </NativeSelect>
 </FormControl>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my own little way with yalls help. here's how I did it.

```
handleScheduleChange = (idx) => (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      schedule: this.state.schedule.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === idx) {
          return {
            ...item,
            [name]: value
          }
        }
        return item;
      })
    });
   console.log(this.state.schedule[idx]);
  };
```

```
<td>
                                    <FormControl className={classes.margin}>
                                      <InputLabel htmlFor="openClosed">O/C</InputLabel>
                                      <NativeSelect
                                        id="openClosed"
                                        name="monOpen"
                                        value={this.state.schedule[idx].monOpen}
                                        onChange={this.handleScheduleChange(idx)}
                                        input={<BootstrapInput />}
                                      >
                                        <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                                        <option value={"0"}>Open</option>
                                        <option value={"1"}>Closed</option>
                                      </NativeSelect>
                                    </FormControl>
</td>
```

whats important is that you give each component a name value that coincides with the value in state you want to change,  also pass in the index of the array so you update the correct one.  This works consistently so you can pass it to multiple functions if they all access the same array in state, for this example I have this.state.schedule